# Create a stacked bar chart from data frame

Tags: dataframe, plot, bar-chart

got this data frame which i want to make into a stacked bar chart with the columns on the x axis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMGRb.jpg)

tried using barplot but just recive error 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
tried using ggplot(dataframe) and just returns grey rectangle